# Why is F5 returning rounded numbers in the script output window, when F9 is returning the correct value in the query result window

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I execute the query using F5 the result is rounding a decimal value up.  When I execute the query using F9 the decimal value is correct.

```
SELECT SW_UNIQUE_ID, SW_TOTAL_TRANSACTIONS, SW_PROCESSED, SW_REMOVED, 
SW_AMOUNT_PROCESSED
FROM SWBATCH
WHERE SW_UNIQUE_ID = 1
```

The correct result in the query result window is

```
1, 977, 977, 0, 55607906.17
```

The incorrect (rounded) result in the script output window is

```
1, 977, 977, 0, 55607906.2
```

Comment: Which tool are you using to see the results?

Comment: I am using sqldeveloper on an oracle 12c database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLPlus style column formatting for numbers is coming into play.

You can bypass this by using SET SQLFORMAT ANSICONSOLE

```
set sqlformat ansiconsole
select 55607906.17 numbers from dual;

NUMBERS       
   55607906.17
```

Or you can set the format yourself in your script.

```
column numbers format 999999999.99
select 55607906.17 numbers from dual;
```

[image]

Comment: I’ll never understand why the default is to change the output to something incorrect!  but it fixed my issue.  I also took a look at your site, very helpful :-)

Comment: When setting “set sqlformat ansiconsole” the data vaue is correct but the column heading and data are now misaligned.

Comment: @SteveBucknall whether it's correct or not depends on your perspective. the default is to round the number...it made sense I guess when the SQLPlus devs built this about 30 years ago